# "I love bike riders." v. "I love the bike riders" Does this sentence need an article?

Tags: definite-articles

> I love bike riders.

Does this sentence need an article? If it doesn't, why? I'm confused because for generalization we need *The*. However I feel like in this particular sentence *The* can't be used.

Comment: No, for generalisation we don't need _the_! The sentence only needs an article if you are referring to a particular group of riders - 'I love the bike riders who stopped to help me yesterday'.

Comment: What do the dashes represent?